# Eclipse feature patch doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, birt, equinox

**I'd like to patch** (Luna SR2) BIRT's `org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml` **plugin**.

When replacing the plugin jar manually with my patched version everything works just fine.

Now I tried creating a feature patch.
[I created a feature patch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_UI/Howto/Create_Feature_Patch) which contains the patched version of this plugin.

However, after installing the feature patch (which completes successfully), the patch seems not to be applied. 
Additionally, I cannot find my patched jar inside the eclipse installation directory, so something seemed to went wrong.
No errors are shown in the log file.

**Any hints to resolve this (or how to debug such issues) would be just perfect.**

My feature patch `feature.xml` looks like (description/copyright tags removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.bug.patch"
      label="BIRT datatools patch"
      version="1.0.0"
      provider-name="MRalwasser">

   <requires>
      <import feature="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.feature" version="1.12.0.v201406061321-7D7U7OEVVFNSGfJoIz0Of" patch="true"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

Comment: "after installing" How did you install?

Comment: Can you try to put your JAR into the `dropins/` folder and restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to referenve the exact new version of your plugin instead of the wildcard "0.0.0" you provided.

I was able to patch different Eclipse features successfully with the following instructions from Andrew Niefer blog posts.

- [Patching features with p2](http://aniefer.blogspot.de/2009/06/patching-features-with-p2.html)
- [Patching Features (Part 2)](http://aniefer.blogspot.de/2009/06/patching-features-part-2.html)

**Additional Hint:** I was only able to apply feature patches in installed products and not inside the Eclipse IDE as Target.